# Wireshark through vpn

Tags: vpn, openvpn

- I use `Wireshark` to sniff return traffic on my machine

However, it only gives me the IP address of my VPN.

How do I sniff out the traffic after it has been decrypted on my machine?

My filter is something like:

```
ip.src == 192.168.1.x
udp.port == xxxx
data.length = x.
```

I am using OpenVPN and need the returned decrypted information.

Any ideas about what's going on?

Comment: Short answer: You can't. Decrypted data is not transmitted anywhere on the network. It is decrypted after being received so wireshark doesn't pick it up. VPN <---> Wireshark <---> You. Both links are encryped. You cannot see it.

Comment: Ok so there is no way to do it without leaking my own IP by sudo killall openvpn I can get what i want then but that leaks my IP which must be a no no

Comment: There must be an output from openvpn that can be monitored locally surely

Comment: @smokingjay Why would privacy software keep logs?

Comment: They dont but killing vpn to get my info will leak my real IP so i need the info without disconnecting

Comment: Which port does the decrypted content come from then i could sniff on that?

Comment: I am new so i dont know

Comment: Why would it come on any port??

Comment: Open vpn uses port 1194 i want to know how to sniff the traffic after its been unencrypted by my vpn client it leaves my machine encrypted and comes back encrypted then is decrypted by my machine i beleive

Comment: Surely there must be a local output port on my machine i can sniff on for the decrypted data but only me obviously

Comment: 1194 is for ENCRYPTED data. It gets downloaded and decrypted. I don't think you understand how networking works.

Comment: Well no im not a professional clearly thats why im asking but i do appreciate your help thank you

Comment: I just need to get some information anonymously via wireshark is there any other way

Comment: Let me put it into another way. The purpose of a VPN is to *specifically* protect against what you are trying to do.

Comment: I know all this a vpn is a virtual private network using the public networking infrastucture and the encryption is what makes it the (virtual) private network just like you were in a wired local area network (LAN) i do know quite a bit about networking im just home educated through books etc i just thoughts seems as i encrypted the comms i maybe be able to sniff the returned decrypted comms but clearly not. I thank you for your help and shall continue in my hobbie

Comment: I posted it as an answer. Accept it so this question can go to rest ^^

Comment: This question was not an argument lmao your answer has been taken onboard and once again thank you i now know it cant be done i will just have to get my info another way

Comment: I mean accept it as check the checkmark below for the question to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't.

At no point is unencrypted data transmitted on your network interfaces.

What you are asking is exactly what VPNs are designed to protect you from.